# Solution to highlight text in call notes based on a list of words?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Any ideas on a SFDC.com based native solution (not buying third pary app's) that can scan call records / notes and identify keywords (based on a word list) in the call records. The solutions goal is to identify inappropriate words in call notes (e.g the word bribe).

Possible Solution (Need help with solving point 4 or open to completely new ideas):

1. Create a table / List / object with the word list that needs to be scanned (e.g the word 'bribe' would be in that list)
2. Export existing call record data into a database and perform a SQL join with 'word list' to identify calls with the word bribe (this will be a monthly process)
3. Load the suspect calls back into SFDC for examination by say managers / auditors etc
4. **Is there a way to highlight the words that were picked up by the SQL process in the call notes that were identified as suspect. Perhaps a SFDC formatting class that maybe available. This is the part that I dont have an initial solution for. The goal is to make it easier for a manager to know which word caused the call note to be flagged without having to manually scan for words in the call note.**

Also although this is not ideal are you aware of any third party solutions that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the records that have been flagged you can then perform what you need to:

VF Page 
1. Create a wrapper to hold the record value and a STRING with the text
2. Using the keyword list, replace any values from the keyword list with

**VALUE**

3. Display the string on the VF Page instead of the field. (Requires a VF page)

If the call notes uses a rich text field, then you can simply update the field in the record once you do the replace

Just thinking out loud

To expand a bit, if you are just rewriting the test back to the field in a ditch text field

1. Have a custom setting with the keywords
2. On a before update trigger

iterate over the trigger records check if the text contains the keywords and replace them with some html formatting

so something like:

```
trigger keyWordHighlight on xxx(Before insert, before update){

   Map<String,CUSTOMSETTING__c> keyword_map = CUSTOMSETTING__c.getAll();

   for(XXXX rec : trigger.new){
        if(!string.isBLANK(rec.FIELD__c)){
           for(String keywrd : keyword_map.keyset()){
                if(rec.FIELD__c.contains(keyword))
                     rec.FIELD__C = rec.FIELD__c.replace(keywrd,'<b>' + keywrd + '</b>');
           }
        }

    }    
}
```

Comment: Eric thanks a ton for your response! I dont know visual force that well so I am having some difficulty following your suggestion. Could you elaborate on your suggestion explaining with a little bit more detail. When you say keyword list are you referring to the list of words that need to be searched (e.g. word bribe)?  What is text 2 ? Thanks again!

Comment: @ThinkFirst - See updated answer. May require some tweaking

Comment: Thx Eric! I was trying to mark your answer as useful but I dont have 15 reputation points yet.  Is there something else I can do to indicate that your answer was helpful / mark answer as solved?

Comment: @ThinkFirst - Click the Check mark to mark it as answered